# How to enter non-ascii characters using hex or octal codes in vi

Tags: vim, binary

I'm trying to write a golfing library for postscript. But it needs to be condensed itself. So I need a convenient way to type-in arbitrary bytes within mostly ascii text.

I know this can easily be done with absolutely any programming language, but can I do it in vi? (`:help octal` was no help).

*Edit:* Here's the resulting [golfing library for postscript](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/G/blob/master/G). Fortunately, I realized early on that golfing the library itself was a stupid idea and I did not do that.

Comment: If Vim is available, [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters#By_character_value) might help

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108020/can-vim-display-ascii-characters-only-and-treat-other-bytes-as-binary-data

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
:help i_CTRL-V_digit
```

In insert mode, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by

- a decimal number (0-255)
- `o` then an octal number (o0-o377, i.e., 255 is the maximum value)
- `x` then a hex number (x00-xFF, i.e., 255 is the maximum value)
- `u` then a 4-hexchar Unicode sequence
- `U` then an 8-hexchar Unicode sequence

Decimal and octal numbers are limited to three digits. 
Decimal numbers less than 100 may include leading zeroes,
which are ignored. 
Octal numbers less than 100<sub>oct</sub> (i.e., 64)
may include leading zeroes, but they are not required. 
Octal numbers greater than or equal to 100<sub>oct</sub>
may *not* include leading zeroes
(but you may type a leading <kbd>o</kbd> if you want to).

You can terminate a number by typing a character
that is not a valid digit for that radix. 
For example,

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>   
  <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> → `A`.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>   
  <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> → `Ab`.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> 
  <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> → `!`.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> 
  <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> → `!9`.

Regular (one-octet) hex numbers are limited to two digits. 
As with the above, you can repeat the radix character
(e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> 
<kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> → `A`) 
for characters specified by hex codes. 
`o` and `x` are case-insensitive.

Comment: To add some more tips: the decimal number must be between 0-255. The hex number between x00-xFF.

Comment: ascii esaple is ctrl+v `x1b` (for ascii color sequences)

Comment: A reminder that if you are in Windows and remapped Ctrl+V to Paste, you can use Ctrl+Q in Insert mode in its place.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426896/vim-ctrl-v-conflict-with-windows-paste

Answer (score 20):

I assume that you use `vim`, because  **`:help`**`octal` is a vim's command. On some systems `vi` is just a symlink to `vim` which runs it in vi-compatible mode.

In vim:

- You can enter unicode characters from basic multilingual plane you can use:
   Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then enter four digit hex unicode code.
- Another option is digraphs. You can read more about them in `vim`'s help (`help: dig`).
  Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and then two-character sequence.
  You can list sequences supported in you vim usig command `:digraph` .

In nvi, vi and elsewhere:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and hit <kbd>U</kbd> and then enter unicode hex code.

Comment: I think that `Ctrl+V` is for entering **decimal** digits, if not followed by `x`

Comment: @Carlos is correct. This answer is wrong. Alan's answer is correct.